# How to restrict JS applied to a block only to block visible pages?

Tags: 6, javascript

I am using Drupal 6. I have added the javascript to my block using hook_theme as shown below.

```
function theme_custom($text) {

        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/sample.js');
        $output =  t($text);
        return $output;
}
```

I am using `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` in my sample.js. I want this js to be loaded only on the pages where the block is set to be visible, but drupal loads this js on all the pages. This makes my script to run on all the pages, increasing the load to the server on every page load. So, how to restrict this js to be loaded only where the block is visible? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hook_block you can show the js wherever the block renders.

```
function hook_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0) {
   $block['content'] = 
   switch($op){
     case 'view':
      switch ($delta) {
        case 'header_block'://block name
        //here you add that js
          drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/sample.js');
          $block['content'] = theme('header_theme');
          break;       
      }         
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Even this method gives me the same result. The JS is getting attached to all the pages. I want it to get attached only where the block is set to be visible.

Comment: Just change it to `$content = theme('header_theme');  if (!empty($content)) { drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/sample.js'); $block['content'] = $content; }`

Comment: Are you enabled js aggregation in drupal?

Comment: No, I have js aggregation disabled.

Comment: Did you canfigure this block in admin page like "show this block to the follwing page" - block configuration

Comment: Yes. I have the block configured to display only on the front page. But the js is getting attached to all the pages.

Comment: did you mention it should display to <front> for front page or like node/23 or node/1 ?

Comment: I have `<front>` in the page specific settings and the block is displayed only in the front page, but the script is loading in all the pages.

Comment: If you used my code (hook_block) then comment the line drupal_add_js and check whether the js is adding or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2597/discussion-between-vivek-and-sathishkumar)

Answer (score 1):

If this apply css to individual blocks / nodes become a frequent requirment take a look at [code per node](http://drupal.org/project/cpn), we have found it very useful for our knowledge system when we sometimes rely on custom code for advanced jquery data tables or charts etc.

Comment: I tried code per node module. Even this module attaches the js on all the pages. But anyways, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean by attaches the js to all pages? It doesn't seem to in our implementation when using nodes. Can you elaborate? What caching do you use?

Comment: I have normal caching mode and page compression enabled . I have a block which is visible only in the front page, and I have this script `$(document).ready( function() { alert("Test"); } )};` written in the text area provided by code per node module. Now I expect this alert message to be displayed only in the front page, but instead it gets displayed in all the pages i.e the script is attached to all the pages. So this is what happens to me. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? I will be very glad if you could help me.

Comment: Ill test on my environment now and report back shortly...

Comment: Tested and the js doesn't persist across pages, I done exactly  same as you and the js alert only shows on home page. It must be something on your configuration...?